# Fitting two peaks with gauss in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

Curve_fit is not fit properly. I'm trying to fit experimental data with `curve_fit`. The data is imported from a `.txt` file to a array:

```
d = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
data_x          = np.array(d[:, 0])
data_y          = np.array(d[:, 2])
data_y_err      = np.array(d[:, 3])
```

Since i know there must be two peaks, my model is a sum of two gaussian curves:

```
def model_dGauss(x, xc, A, y0, w, dx):
    P = A/(w*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
    mu1 = (x - (xc - dx/3))/(2*w**2)
    mu2 = (x - (xc + 2*dx/3))/(2*w**2)    
    return y0 + P * ( np.exp(-mu1**2) + 0.5 * np.exp(-mu2**2))
```

Using values for the guess is very sensitive to my guess values. Where is the point of fitting data if just nearly perfect fitting parameter will provide a result? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

```
t = np.linspace(8.4, 10, 300)
guess_dG = [32, 1, 10, 0.1, 0.2]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model_dGauss, data_x, data_y, p0=guess_dG, sigma=data_y_err, absolute_sigma=True)
A, xc, y0, w, dx = popt
```

Plotting the data

```
plt.scatter(data_x, data_y)
plt.plot(t, model_dGauss(t1,*popt))
plt.errorbar(data_x, data_y, yerr=data_y_err)
```

yields:

[Plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsfPS.png)

The result is just a straight line at the bottom of my graph while the evaluated parameters are not that bad. How can that be?

Comment: The snippets are somewhat incomplete. Despite the fact that you should provide the data, you use `t` and `t1` without defining the latter, while the first has completely wrong range.  Moreover, the start values do not seem too good. When putting proper ranges fit works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A complete example of code is always appreciated (and, ahem, usually expected here on SO).  To remove much of the confusion about using `curve_fit` here, allow me to suggest that you will have an easier time using `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) and especially its builtin model functions and its use of named parameters.   With lmfit, your code for two Gaussians plus a constant offset might look like this:

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, ConstantModel

# start with 1 Gaussian + Constant offset:
model = GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') + ConstantModel()

# this model will have parameters named:  
# p1_amplitude, p1_center, p1_sigma, and c.  
# here we give initial values to these parameters
params = model.make_params(p1_amplitude=10, p1_center=32, p1_sigma=0.5, c=10)

# optionally place bounds on parameters (probably not needed here):
params['p1_amplitude'].min = 0.
## params['p1_center'].vary = False # fix a parameter from varying in fit

# now do the fit (including weighting residual by 1/y_err):
result = model.fit(data_y, params, x=data_x, weights=1.0/data_y_err)

# print out param values, uncertainties, and fit statistics, or get best-fit
# parameters from `result.params`
print(result.fit_report())

# plot results
plt.errorbar(data_x, data_y, yerr=data_y_err, label='data')
plt.plot(data_x, result.best_fit, label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

To add a second Gaussian, you could just do

```
model = GaussianModel(prefix='p1_') + GaussianModel(prefix='p2_') + ConstantModel()

# and then:  
params = model.make_params(p1_amplitude=10, p1_center=32, p1_sigma=0.5, c=10, 
                           p2_amplitude=2, p2_center=31.75, p1_sigma=0.5)
```

and so on.

Your model has the two gaussian sharing or at least having "linked" values - the `sigma` values should be the same for the two peaks and the amplitude of the 2nd is half that of the 1st.  As defined so far, the 2-Gaussian model has all the parameters being independent.  But lmfit has a mechanism for setting constraints on any parameter by giving an algebraic expression in terms of other parameters.   So, for example, you could say

```
params['p2_sigma'].expr = 'p1_sigma'
params['p2_amplitude'].expr = 'p1_amplitude / 2.0'
```

Now, `p2_amplitude` and `p2_sigma` will not be independently varied in the fit but will be constrained to have those values.